# Cant choice right Cookie to login with python code

Tags: python, authentication, scrapy, python-requests

I'm trying to implement the following working code:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()

jar.set('key', 'value')
session.cookies = jar

r = session.get('https://example.com/user/info')
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
```

I am trying to get user info using above code. I logged in my account from browser and have this [Cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuBgP.png) but I dont know which key/value is supposed to be used to get user info. The code is working for other website with right Cookie. Any ideas about choicing right key/value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inspect and find Cookies you will see like:

```
Cookie: sess-is='123456'; other1-key=other1-val; other2-key=other2-val; otherN- 
key=otherN-val;
```

most browser keep cookie in this format. In your case:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
jar = requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar()

jar.set('Cookie', 'sess-is='123456'; other1-key=other1-val; other2-key=other2-val; 
otherN-key=otherN-val;')

session.cookies = jar

r = session.get('https://example.com/user/info')
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
```

Have a great web scraping :)

Comment: Have you tried to login with username and password? Cookies may expire after some time

Comment: I researched but it is fine for me thank you! It was my first question and got answered!!!